# OS X. How to run console app with parameters?

Tags: swift, macos, bash, console

I'm trying to run my own console app with parameters. The app is written in swift language and need one parameter from outside for work. In code I'm getting first parameter in such way: `Process.arguments[1]`(0 parameter - path to application).

From terminal I'm running operation: `open MyApp --args test_argument`

But it is not working. I don't know why. When I'm hardcoding this parameter all works fine, but when I'm trying to get it from outside, it is not...

Do somebody know what I'm doing wrong? Maybe I'm passing parameter in wrong way? Or getting is not correct? Thanks.

Comment: `Process.arguments[1]` is correct for getting the first argument, although that will crash with array index out of range if you don't pass any arguments.  Try dropping `open` and just run it as `MyApp  test_argument`.

Comment: @vacawama I'm getting -bash: MyApp: command not found

Comment: You need to give the path to the app.  If it is in your current directory `./MyApp test_argument`.

Comment: @vacawama thanks man. It works. I think that if I'm in directory already I don't need to give path to application again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Process.arguments[1]` is correct for accessing the first argument, but be careful because this will crash with **fatal error: Array index out of range** if you don't pass any arguments.  You should first check to make sure `Process.arguments.count > 1` before accessing `Process.arguments[1]`.

Your problem is how you are running your app.  You just need to specify the app name followed by any arguments:

```
MyApp test_argument
```

If `MyApp` is not in your `$PATH` or in your current directory, it won't be found.  You can edit `~/.bash_profile` to add an additional path to `$PATH`.  This file gets executed (sourced) each time you open a new Terminal.  To execute it after you just edited it, type `. ~/.bash_profile`.

For example, if you keep your apps in your `~/Documents` directory, edit `~/.bash_profile` and add this line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/Documents
```